# Finding values that are causing NaN for Mean statistic function in Graylog2

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I have a simple request log where each record has an execution time in seconds, under `exec_time` property. It should always be a number (lower the better). Based on that property I have dashboard widget that shows its Mean value and it was working just fine until recently. Now it shows `NaN`.

My guess is that there's one or more records with `exec_time` that's not numeric. How can I find these records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your request logs, and iterate over them with a simple script to check every value individually. Print out the ones that are wrong. With no other information my guess is you have a mis-tagged non-number field feeding into "exec_time", an empty (null, none) value, something too large, something too small, or a corrupted entry somewhere.

Comment: I may not like the answer (that I have to write my own code that looks through multiple indexes to find non-numerical values), but that appears to be the solution here.